# Ошибка "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" при парсинге Json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Я сделал серверную часть на java, который по ссылке мне выдает **JSON** - http://139.59.164.239:8080/remindme.server2/reminders

Мне нужно спарсить этот JSON в массив java объектов и вывести всё это в `listview` в Android. Я использую **Retrofit2**, и при вызове метода `enqueue` я попадаю в метод `onFailure` с exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

Мой код ниже:

**1. MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "TAG";

    private ListView listView;
    private View     parentView;

    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private ContactAdapter     adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull final View view) {

                /**
                 * Checking Internet Connection
                 */
                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {

                    //Creating an object of our api interface
                    ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();
                    Call<ContactList> call = api.getMyJSON();
                    Log.d(TAG, "" + call.isExecuted());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Я в после  Call<ContactList> call = api.getMyJSON()  ");
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Я в onResponse ");
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                contactList = response.body().getContacts();
                                adapter = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Я в else ");
                                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_some_thing_wrong, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable t) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Я в onFailure" + t.getMessage().toString());
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_internet_connection_not_available, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**2. Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("remindDate")
    @Expose
    private String remindDate;

    /**
     * @return The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return The name
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * @return The email
     */
    public String getRemindDate() {
        return remindDate;
    }
}
```

**3. ContactList.java**

```
public class ContactList {

    //@SerializedName("remind")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @return The contacts
     */
    public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    /**
     * @param contacts The contacts
     */
    public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }
}
```

**4. RetroClient.java**

```
public class RetroClient {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://139.59.164.239:8080";

    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    public static ApiService getApiService() {
    return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

**5. ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("/remindme.server2/reminders")
    Call<ContactList> getMyJSON();
}
```

В итоге выходит ошибка в методе OnFailure:  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $**
Я новичок в этой теме, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее решить. Спасибо!

Comment: обычно у json парсеров есть опции, с помощью которых можно задать, что бы одиночный элемент всегда воспринимался как массив

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам в json приходит массив, а вы пытаетесь спарсить его в объект, о чём и говорит возникшая ошибка.

Замените в **ApiService.java** `Call<ContactList> getMyJSON();` на `Call<List<Contact>> getMyJSON();` и работайте дальше непосредственно со списком:

```
Call<List<Contact>> call = api.getMyJSON();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
      ...
```

Comment: я заменил, но как мне теперь в массив contactlist поместить все объекты? Скриншот - http://joxi.ru/a2XxgwYh1zn4o2    Я раньше делал это методом .getContacts из класса ContactList, но этот класс уже не используется, отсюда и вопрос на что заменить этот метод

Comment: Один вариант это изменить тип `contactList` с `ArrayList` на `List`. Другой делать `contactList.addAll(response.body())`.

Comment: ок спасибо! буду пробовать, второй вариант как по мне легче в реализации))

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Спасибо тебе большое! Замучился я уже с этим JSON'ом!